# How to access io instance in a third part file?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I need to access my socket.io instance in some differents files, how do you make it works?

Here is what i tried:

**main.js**

```
var app = express();
var sockets = require('./sockets');
sockets.listen(app)
```

**sockets.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io');
exports.listen = function(app) {
    io = io.listen(app);
    //...
}
exports.io = io;
```

**SomeClass.js**

```
var io = require('./sockets').io;

var SomeClass = function() {
    var Clients = io.sockets.clients('room');
    //io is undefined...
}

exports.SomeClass = SomeClass;
```

Comment: You have a typo, it's `exports`, not `exprots`.

Comment: So are you still having any problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your file, `io.sockets` is undefined because you are starting your server incorrectly. Socket.IO expects a HTTP server instance, and you are instead passing an Express instance. You are also trying to change a variable after it has been exported, and that does not work. This is what you should be doing:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server):

server.listen(80);
```

If you still wanted to split this up into files, you would have to put your Socket.IO instance in your main application, and pass it to other modules when requiring them.